# Deletes a specific cell while moving the line to the left

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame where the error has crept. Example:

```
    data1   data2   data3
0   111     555 
1   222     666 
2   A       333     777
3   444     888
```

I would like to remove the letter 'A' from the column 'data1' while simultaneously moving all the rest of the row 2 to the left. To get the result in the form:

```
    data1   data2   data3
0   111     555
1   222     666
2   333     777
3   444     888
```

How to do it?

Comment: Your df is not directly reproducible. This minimizes your chance of getting an answer.

Comment: @Kanak I did not throw the whole code because my problem is only a small percentage of the problem. That's why I presented it on the theoretical example :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the one of the solution .

```
df=df.apply(pd.to_numeric,errors='coerce').\
    apply(lambda x: sorted(x, key=pd.isnull), 1).fillna('')
df
Out[931]: 
   data1  data2 data3
0  111.0  555.0      
1  222.0  666.0      
2  333.0  777.0      
3  444.0  888.0
```

Comment: In principle, it should suffice, since all cells except the ones that are wrong are numbers. I will test it. Thanks :)

Comment: @TomaszPrzemski let me know the test result :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
d = df.replace('A', np.nan)
a = d.isnull().values.argsort(1)

pd.DataFrame(
    d.values[np.arange(len(a))[:, None], a],
    d.index, d.columns)

  data1 data2 data3
0   111   555   NaN
1   222   666   NaN
2   333   777   NaN
3   444   888   NaN
```

Comment: Can this solution be applied with the indication of a particular column?